# Bootstrap Accordion does not remain on the same tab, after copying the URL to other location

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

Below is the javascript & HTML code for Bootstrap accordion, that I am using in my Project.

**Issue is:** If user is on the 2nd Tab i.e., `RELATED SOPs` and then opens any of the nested tab inside it, and then copy the URL from the address bar and paste it to any *another browser* or *another tab* of same browser, then always nested tab of 1st Tab i.e., `QESH MANUAL` is opened in place of 2nd Tab & its nested tab (last opened by user).

**EDIT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("ul#tab li:first").addClass("aktif");
        $("div.tab_icerik").hide();
        $("div.tab_icerik:first").show();
        $("ul#tab li").click(function (e) {
            var index = $(this).index();
            $("ul#tab li").removeClass("aktif");
            $(this).addClass("aktif");
            $("div.tab_icerik").hide();
            $("div.tab_icerik:eq(" + index + ")").show();
            return false
        });

        $(".tabv2").click(function () {
            var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
            var thatId = $(this).siblings().attr('id')
            $('[class^="tabv2-"]').hide();
            $('.' + thisId).show();
            $('.tabv2').removeClass('tabv2-active');
            $(this).addClass('tabv2-active');
        });

        $(".tabv2plain").click(function () {
            var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
            var thatId = $(this).siblings().attr('id')
            $('[class^="tabv2plain-"]').hide();
            $('.' + thisId).show();
            $('.tabv2plain').removeClass('tabv2plain-active');
            $(this).addClass('tabv2plain-active');
        });

        $(".tabv3plain").click(function () {
            var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
            var thatId = $(this).siblings().attr('id')
            $('[class^="tabv3plain-"]').hide();
            $('.' + thisId).show();
            $('.tabv3plain').removeClass('tabv3plain-active');
            $(this).addClass('tabv3plain-active');
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
<script>
    function myFunction() {       
        window.location.hash = "#One";
        //var a = "QESH MANUAL" + location.hash;
        //document.getElementById("One").innerHTML = a;
    }

    function myFunction2() {
        window.location.hash = "#Two";
    }

    function myFunction3() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseOne";
    }

    function myFunction4() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseOneOne";
    }

    function myFunction5() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseOneOne1";
    }

    function myFunction6() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseOneTwo";
    }

    function myFunction7() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseOneTwo1";
    }

    function myFunction8() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseOneTwo2";
    }

    function myFunction9() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseOneTwo3";
    }

    function myFunction10() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseOneTwo4";
    }

    function myFunction11() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseOneTwo5";
    }

    function myFunction12() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseOneTwo6";
    }

    function myFunction13() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseOneThree";
    }

    function myFunction14() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseOneThree1";
    }

    function myFunction15() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseOneFour";
    }

    function myFunction16() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseOneFour1";
    }

    function myFunction17() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseTwo";
    }

    function myFunction18() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseTwo1";
    }

    function myFunction19() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseThree";
    }

    function myFunction20() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseThree1";
    }

    function myFunction21() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseFour";
    }

    function myFunction22() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseFour1";
    }

    //2nd Tab Menus

    function myFunction23() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseFive";
    }

    function myFunction24() {
        window.location.hash = "#collapseFive1";
    }
</script>

    <div>
            <div class="row" style="padding-top:5px">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul id="tab">
                        <li class="">
                            <a onclick="myFunction()" href="#One">QESH MANUAL</a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="margin-left:3px;" class="aktif">
                            <a onclick="myFunction2()" href="#Two">RELATED SOPs</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="padding-top:5px">
                <div class="tab_icerik" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span style="display:block;">
                            <div id="accordionA1" class="panel-group">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#E51400; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA1" onclick="myFunction3()" href="#collapseOne"> CONSTRUCTION</a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <!-- SECOND LEVEL ACCORDION START -->
                                            <div id="accordionA2" class="panel-group">
                                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA2" onclick="myFunction4()" href="#collapseOneOne">QESH MANUAL</a>
                                                        </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="collapseOneOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <div class="group row clear" id="tabsv2plain">
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain tabv2plain-active" id="tabv2plain-1">
                                                                    <a onclick="myFunction5()" href="#collapseOneOne1">QESH Manual</a>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA2" onclick="myFunction6()" href="#collapseOneTwo">PROCEDURES MANUALS</a>
                                                        </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="collapseOneTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <div class="group row clear" id="Div1">
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-2">

                                                                    <a onclick="myFunction7()" href="#collapseOneTwo1">Tender &amp; Contract Procedure Manual</a>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-3">

                                                                    <a onclick="myFunction8()" href="#collapseOneTwo2">Procurement Procedure Manual</a>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-4">

                                                                    <a onclick="myFunction9()" href="#collapseOneTwo3">Pre-Construction &amp; Planning Procedure Manual</a>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-5">

                                                                    <a onclick="myFunction10()" href="#collapseOneTwo4">Project Implementation &amp; Management Procedure Manual</a>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-6">

                                                                    <a onclick="myFunction11()" href="#collapseOneTwo5">Post-Construction Procedure Manual</a>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-7">

                                                                    <a onclick="myFunction12()" href="#collapseOneTwo6">Management System Administration Procedure Manual</a>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA2" onclick="myFunction13()" href="#collapseOneThree">QESH POLICY</a>
                                                        </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="collapseOneThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <div class="group row clear" id="Div2">
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-8">
                                                                    <a onclick="myFunction14()" href="#collapseOneThree1">QESH Policy</a>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA2" onclick="myFunction15()" href="#collapseOneFour">QESH OBJECTIVE</a>
                                                        </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="collapseOneFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <div class="group row clear" id="Div3">
                                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-9">
                                                                    <a onclick="myFunction16()" href="#collapseOneFour1">QESH Objective</a>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- SECOND LEVEL ACCORDION END -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#E51400; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA1" onclick="myFunction17()" href="#collapseTwo">SUNWAY ENGINEERING                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="group row clear" id="Div4">
                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-10">
                                                    <a onclick="myFunction18()" href="#collapseTwo1">QESH Manual</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#E51400; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA1" onclick="myFunction19()" href="#collapseThree">SUNWAY GEOTECHNICS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="group row clear" id="Div5">
                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-11">
                                                 <a onclick="myFunction20()" href="#collapseThree1">QESH Manual</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#E51400; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionA1" onclick="myFunction21()" href="#collapseFour">SUNWAY CONCRETE PRODUCTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="group row clear" id="Div6">
                                                <div class="tabv2plain" id="tabv2plain-12">
                                                  <a onclick="myFunction22()" href="#collapseFour1">QESH Manual</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <span style="display:block; padding:10px;">
                            <div class="tabplaincontent">
                                <div class="tabv2plain-1" style="display:block;">
                                    One Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-2" style="display:none;">
                                    Two Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-3" style="display:none;">
                                    Three Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-4" style="display:none;">
                                    Four Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-5" style="display:none;">
                                    Five Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-6" style="display:none;">
                                    Six Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-7" style="display:none;">
                                    Seven Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-8" style="display:none;">
                                    Eight Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-9" style="display:none;">
                                    Nine Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-10" style="display:none;">
                                    Ten Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-11" style="display:none;">
                                    Eleven Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv2plain-12" style="display:none;">
                                    Twelve Content
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab_icerik" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span style="display:block;">
                            <div id="accordionB1" class="panel-group">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#E51400; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionB1" onclick="myFunction23()" href="#collapseFive">FINANCE &amp; ADMIN</a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="group row clear" id="tabsv3plain">
                                                <div class="tabv3plain" id="tabv3plain-1">
                                                    <a onclick="myFunction24()" href="#collapseFive1">General</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <span style="display:block; padding:10px;">
                            <div class="tabplaincontent">
                                <div class="tabv3plain-1" style="display:block;">
                                    Thirteen Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv3plain-2" style="display:none;">
                                    Fourteen Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv3plain-3" style="display:none;">
                                    Fifteen Content
                                </div>
                                <div class="tabv3plain-4" style="display:none;">
                                    Sixteen Content
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

For above requirement, I added `window.location.hash` to uniquely identify each Accordion tab in URL.
Now, when I click on any of the Accordion tab, I can see a unique name (based on selected tab) with hash at the end in URL

**Example:**

```
localhost:49963/Test.aspx#collapseThree1
```

Again, when I copy the URL (which include a unique name for each selected tab) always the 1st Accordion tab is opened i.e., CONSTRUCTION --> Quesh Manual --> Quesh Manual ; in place of last selected tab by user. Still the same issue persist.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: That because you don't read url hash in `$(document).ready`. You need to check if url contains a hash for particular tab/item and activate it. By default, you always opens the first tab/first item